# Plural noun with signgular adjectives

Tags: adjectives, plural-forms

Suppose I have one green hat and one blue hat. How should I describe them? Each of the following sounds flawed to me.

1. > A green and a blue hats.

This doesn't sound grammatical.

2. > A green hat and a blue hat.

This sounds redundant, particularly if it's a long word instead of hat.

3. > Green and blue hats.

This doesn't capture that there's exactly one of each color.

4. > Two hats, green and blue.

This is ambiguous, because each hat could be green and blue.

Answer (score 3):

Pronouns are your friend!

> A green hat and a blue one.

Works fine with long expressions

> A green wooden toy with a bell and a blue one.

You can also use the structure

> Two hats, one green and one blue.